# Reusing FBO or dynamic texture contents across multiple frames

Tags: opengl-es

I am working with OpenGL ES 3.0. I am at a point of trying to optimize my rendering implementation and have run into issues.

I am using offscreen FBOs and rendering into textures to be able to do some processing before rendering the final processed texture on screen. My initial implementation was updating the entire texture which is to be rendered on screen for every frame. However, from one frame to the next only a small part of the texture changes (maybe 5% of it) which I can represent with a few triangles, so I thought I may be able to keep the rest of the texture intact and just render this part which has changed.

I have tried a few different approaches and none of them have worked:

1. Calling glDrawArrays() passing to it only the triangles that have changed from previous frame.
2. Using a stencil buffer to mask the area which needs to be changed.
3. Using a scissor box to only render the bounding rectangle of the area that has changed.

All of these approaches gave me the same result - parts of the texture look ok at times, parts of it are garbage and it is flickering heavily. The only way to avoid flickering has been to call glClear without a scissor box enabled, which is something I obviously want to avoid if possible.

I am using the same FBO for each frame and this is the only thing I use the FBO for.

The question here is, am I trying to do something that is not possible? Do I have to do something like render the entire texture first, and then render the parts that have changed (this could potentially be an improvement I guess, if the original shaders are complex).

Comment: Fundamentally the idea is OK. Hard to give any more feedback that that without some specifics and a minimal reproducer that shows the problem. Does it fail the same way everywhere, or only on some GPUs?